# Implementing LinqToTwitter explanation

Tags: c#, delegates

I am having trouble understanding the following property implementation

`public Action < string > GoToTwitterAuthorization { get; set; }`

async void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            pinAuth = new PinAuthorizer
            {
                CredentialStore = new InMemoryCredentialStore
                {
                    ConsumerKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["consumerKey"],
                    ConsumerSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["consumerSecret"]
                },
                 GoToTwitterAuthorization = pageLink => Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)
                    (() => OAuthWebBrowser.Navigate(new Uri(pageLink, UriKind.Absolute))))
            };

```
        await pinAuth.BeginAuthorizeAsync();
    }
```

Does GoToTwitterAuthorization replace the pageLink at runtime?

Comment: The instantiation of  PinAuthorizer then is both setting the property up passing in that property to it.  What does BeginAuthorizeAsync look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GoToTwitterAuthorization does not replace the pageLink,  rather it is utilised in the Navigate method which looks like it will be queued to run on another thread at some point in the future (probably the UI or owning thread)

Action denotes that GoToTwitterAuthorization expects the declaration of a method, much like a delegate, which will be executed when invoked.

When the property is set up this is saying that at some point in the future when this property is called, the body of the lambda will be executed passing in an argument (a string) for pageLink.  Only when GoToTwitterAuthorization is called will pageLink have a value.

So when you call GoToTwitterAuthorization

```
 GoToTwitterAuthorization("http://linktosomesite");
```

In essence what will happen is that  the value pageLink will be substituted where it is encountered in the lambda body, just like any normal method call.  pageLink is the parameter for the lambda statement in this instance and when it is used in the lambda body you can think of it as follows:

```
pageLink => Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action) (() => OAuthWebBrowser.Navigate(new Uri("http://linktosomesite", UriKind.Absolute))))
```

EDIT 2:

I've just looked over the comments and looked at code in the question again . Alot of what I said still stands. But it only just dawned on me how PinAuth is declared and used.

So the GoToTwitterAuthorization property is instantiated when PinAuth is declared in the Windows_Loaded method.  When I first read it I assumed this was a property at the top of the class. Anyway....

Later on this call is made: 
`await pinAuth.BeginAuthorizeAsync();`

So inside the pinAuth BeginAuthorizeAsync method,  the GoToTwitterAuthorization property with the delegate declared will be **called** at  some point.

It pretty much looks like it will be used to authenticate a user secured via OAuth on twitter?.  As I/O is used (going out over the Web) this will pause the execution of the Window_Loaded method and  the BeginAuthorizeAsync methods until a response is received  (freeing up the thread that started the work, momentarily for other stuff).

Once a response is received execution of the BeginAuthorizeAsync method will resume  and then the Window_Loaded method will run to completion.

Im hazarding a guess that the OAuthWebBrowser is an object which represents some kind of stateful Browser control on the form/page and as the Windows_Loaded method executes, when OAUthWebBrowser.Navigate is called this will be visible?

If it is not a control of some sort then this will be going on behind the scenes, and other calls will then be able to use some kind of authenticated token to interact with the site through the browser.

Comment: Then how does pageLink get populated?

Comment: Updated answer I didnt realise Action wasnt typed to anything.

Comment: It compiles fine, I am just after a deeper understanding, the parameter has to be replaced / hold a value that GoToTwitterAuthorization is aware of

Comment: Updated main question as parser replaced tags

Comment: But that is my point - pagelink is not defined in any way as a uri value - the code in the question is exactly how it is

Comment: Scroll across.  A lambda is nothing more than an anonymous method, and parameters to an anonymous method or lambda are used just as they would be in a normal method call.

Comment: I realise that, however, pageLink is never set a value, so your example of somesite is never set - that is the confusing part.

Comment: You must call GoToTwitterAuthorization at some other point in your code passing in a string representing the link. Just like I have stated above. And when it is called the body of the lambda will be exceuted

Comment: No, hence the confusion :-)

Comment: So its never called? Can't you do a search on GoToTwitterAuthorization

Comment: I have done, the value does not get set by the program

Comment: I will amend the question to put the full part in

Comment: Ok that code that sets the lambda up is called and executed as it is setting up what will happen when GoToTwitterAuthorization is called and so when debugging a break point will stop here.  If you where to call the method you would stop on the same break point but break into the the body of the lambda.

Comment: I know what you are saying, but the methods are closed. The function sets the property then calls await pinAuth.BeginAuthorizeAsync();

Comment: Updated question so you can see full call

Comment: May need to post this again as I am still confused